# Android/Firebase - Error while parsing timestamp in GCM event - Null timestamp

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, timestamp, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm building an Android app which will receive push notifications. I've got Firebase Cloud Messaging setup and pretty much working, such that I can send the following payload to a valid token and the notification and data are received.

Using url `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`

```
{
 "to":"<valid-token>",
 "notification":{"body":"BODY TEXT","title":"TITLE TEXT","sound":"default"},
 "data":{"message":"This is some data"}
}
```

My app receives it correctly and can deal with it.

The only slight wrinkle is that I get the following exception thrown in the debug:

```
Error while parsing timestamp in GCM event
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
        at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
        ...
```

It doesn't crash the app, it just looks untidy.

I've tried adding a `timestamp` item to the main payload, the notification, the data, and also tried variations such as `time` but can't seem to get rid of the exception (and google as I might, I can't find an answer).

How do I pass the timestamp so it stops complaining?

Edited: Here is my `onMessageReceived` method, but I think the exception is thrown before it gets here

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        //TODO Handle the data
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: can u post onMessageReceived Methed code.....

Comment: Have updated, though I think the exception is thrown before the first line of that method is called

Comment: Please Stop Notification Payload and Try again And Why you are using Both

Comment: Without the Notification payload, there is no notification shown when the app is not in the foreground. What's the alternative to notification?

Comment: you are trying from Firebase Cansol?

Comment: Please read this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: Hi, did you solve this issue? I am also trying to figure out how to get rid of this exception..

Comment: Having the same issue, everything worked before...

Comment: same problem, with the firebase console works fine

Comment: same problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50819595/error-when-push-notification-by-postman-but-not-when-send-by-firebase-console

Comment: Getting the same problem from backed, but can get notification with postman

Comment: Have added my solution below. In a nutshell, firebase with notifications throws an error, so I handled the notification locally

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Even though `notification` is apparently a supported element (according to the Firebase web docs), the only way I could get rid of the exception was to remove it entirely, and use the `data` section only, and then in my app create a notification (rather than letting firebase do the notification).

I used this site to work out how to raise the notifications: https://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

My notification now looks like the following:

```
    $fields = array("to" => "<valid-token>",
                    "data" => array("data"=>
                                        array(
                                            "message"=>"This is some data",
                                            "title"=>"This is the title",
                                            "is_background"=>false,
                                            "payload"=>array("my-data-item"=>"my-data-value"),
                                            "timestamp"=>date('Y-m-d G:i:s')
                                            )
                                    )
                    );
    ...
    <curl stuff here>
    ...
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
```

My `onMessageReceived` looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            handleDataMessage(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

which calls `handleDataMessage` which looks like this:

```
private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
    Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());

    try {
        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

        String title = data.getString("title");
        String message = data.getString("message");
        boolean isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
        String timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");
        JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");

        // play notification sound
        NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
        notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();

        if (!NotificationUtils.isBackgroundRunning(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(ntcAppManager.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

        } else {
            // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

            showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

this then calls `showNotificationMessage`

```
/**
 * Showing notification with text only
 */
private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);
}
```

And subsequently `notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage`

```
public void showNotificationMessage(String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
    showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, null);
}

public void showNotificationMessage(final String title, final String message, final String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
    // Check for empty push message
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
        return;


    // notification icon
    final int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    mContext,
                    0,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
            );

    final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            mContext);

    final Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
            + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");


    showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
    playNotificationSound();

}

private void showSmallNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {

    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

    inboxStyle.addLine(message);

    Notification notification;
    notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setStyle(inboxStyle)
            .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
            .setContentText(message)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(ntcAppManager.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

More detail in the link above, and it's a lot of handling but at least the exception's gone and I'm in control of the notifications.

Comment: That notification format makes no sense, can you write it as JSON?

Comment: @Gerry, google "php json_encode".  He's using that to encode a php array into json.

Answer (score 2):

I've updated com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging to 17.3.4 and issue disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this same error, I resolved by adding a `ttl` value to the payload.

```
{
   "to":"<valid-token>",
   "notification":{"body":"BODY TEXT","title":"TITLE TEXT","sound":"default"},
   "data":{"message":"This is some data"},
   "ttl": 3600
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I've just set "body" parameter in notification and error dissapeared.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

Upgrading, not only `firebase-messaging`, but all Firebase libraries to the last version. In `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0"  // upgraded
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.0"  // upgraded
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'  // upgraded

    // ...

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.0"  // upgraded

    // ...
}
```

Not all of them are at version 17.x

Answer (score 0):

Format below (no notification body, nor are there any arrays) fixed the timestamp exception for me:

```
{
  "to": "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee",
  "data":  {
      "message": "message",
      "title": "hello",
  }
}
```

Tested fine with http://pushtry.com/

*The only reason I included the long 'eeee...' is that is the exact size of my token.*

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
 "notification" : {
    "title" : "title !",
    "body" : "body !",
    "sound" : "default"
  },
  "condition" : "'xxx' in topics",
  "priority" : "high",
  "data" : {
....
```

by (remove notification) :

```
{
  "condition" : "'xxxx' in topics",
  "priority" : "high",
  "data" : {
    "title" : "title ! ",
     "body" : "BODY",
 ......
}
```

And on you code :
Replace :

```
 @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) { 
           remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
           remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

        }
```

by

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) { 
       remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
       remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case My error was "AndrodManifest.xml"

I miss one service (actually Android studio's firebase assistant is missing my permission. :) )

**original**

```
<service android:name=".fcm.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

**solution**

```
    <service android:name=".fcm.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```