# Error when push notification by postman but not when send by Firebase console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I send a notification to my android app, to a certain device. When i do it from the Firebase Console I don't get **any exception** but when I try to post the notification from Postman i get this on the android Log (the notification is received perfectly and the app doesn't stop, it's just a log exception/warning).

```
W/FirebaseMessaging: Error while parsing timestamp in GCM event
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: s == null
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:570)
        at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:794)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source:62)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzd.zzi(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleIntent(Unknown Source:365)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.run(Unknown Source:26)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

The problem is **NOT** in the onMessagereceived method.

My post json is just the default one:

```
{
  "message":{
    "token" : "cBtsRkkSkmY:APA91bGksorrythisisnottherealtokenSn8bavHz8NLxULB1A9CMGrHIyTDU_o7ifHo666pojgur5WVdjH_a_yLV8QQplDL22FPu8çQXyT_TWRYD13mKpTi-N8cs0oVQ9zUXS",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "Testing",
      "title" : "testiinggg"
      }
   }
 }
```

It is true, there is no timestamp. I can guess that the Firebase Console does the same but with a timestamp.

My problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50795697/android-firebase-error-while-parsing-timestamp-in-gcm-event-null-timestamp) but no solution was found for him because of not enough information.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably the Firebase request sends a timestamp and other data in the request header. Check what is sent and add the necessary headers in your Postman call

Comment: Do post your code for `onMessageReceived()`

Comment: Looking at the decompiled code for `FirebaseMessagingService`, I see the error messsage indicates an internal message field `google.c.a.ts` is null.  Suggest you file a [Firebase support request or bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/).

Comment: @AL. As I said, theres no problem there. There is just a Log.i(); that works perfectly.

Comment: This is a known issue but should not affect your application in anyway other than the warning message in the log. The FCM team is looking into it.

Comment: My app is still not work now. Is there any place to check out the situation?

Comment: @TerryWei, if your app doesn't work, it's certainly not linked to this as this warning doesn't affect the global behaviour of the app.

Comment: OK, I found the problem and solved.

Comment: how did you solve it???

Comment: @TerryWei And you don't want to share you solution with others having the same issue?! Didn't you get the idea of stackoverflow?

Comment: Sorry for the misleading message. As @schtipoun said that's not the fcm's problem, I solved my own problem and it works fine now and I just ignore that warning.

Comment: @Benedict In my case, I fixed using firebaseVersion 15.0.0

Comment: @giankotarola 15.0.0 didn't fixed it for me. same Warning