# Error while parsing timestamp in GCM event - Null Android (onMessageReceived not called)

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Strange problem occur while getting firebase notification. So whenever my app in background and any firebase notification comes then my `onMessageReceived` method not called. Logcat showing below error :-

```
FirebaseMessaging: Error while parsing timestamp in GCM event
   java.lang.NumberFormatException: s == null
       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:570)
       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
       at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb.zzc(Unknown Source:81)
       at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb.zze(Unknown Source:2)
       at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzd(Unknown Source:280)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.run(Unknown Source:26)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source:7)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

or

```
FirebaseMessaging: Error while parsing timestamp in GCM event
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
        at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb.zzc(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb.zze(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzd(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzc.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source)
```

So now I follow this SO question [Android/Firebase - Error while parsing timestamp in GCM event - Null timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50795697/android-firebase-error-while-parsing-timestamp-in-gcm-event-null-timestamp) and change in my server end.

Now server sending `timestamp` into data object like below :-

```
{
  "data": {
    "deeplink": "xyz",
    "timestamp": "2018-08-01 20:49:07"
  },
  "notification": {
    "title": "Some random title",
    "body": "this is a random body"
  }
}
```

Still my `onMessageReceived` method not called. I try so many link but not able to resolve my problem. I

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19004

https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=es-NI#!topic/firebase-talk/iiDlHDhDpQ8

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/issues/784

Comment: See this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50819595/4815718). A comment from Firebaser says:  _This is a known issue but should not affect your application in anyway other than the warning message in the log. The FCM team is looking into it_

Comment: @BobSnyder I dnt think so bcz in my case onMessageReceived not called

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using latest firebase dependency plugin, because Android 'O'will have atleast **com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.0** version.. There after follow the basic steps as [this_link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50795697/android-firebase-error-while-parsing-timestamp-in-gcm-event-null-timestamp) and set channel id as shown  [here](https://medium.com/globallogic-latinoamerica-mobile/firebase-cloud-messaging-warning-updating-to-android-oreo-1343fe894bd5)