# Getting a java.lang.numberformatexception invalid int null in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am using firebase for push notification in my application. I am getting messages. When the app is closed and a notification is received, clicking the notification opens the app but doesn't take to the page I directed. I tried debugging; if the app is open the push notification service is hit, but after closing the app and if a message is received the service breakpoint is not hit.

Later I found this exception:

> Error while parsing timestamp in GCM event java.lang.NumberFormatException invalid int null in android

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
W/FirebaseMessaging: Error while parsing timestamp in GCM event
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:354)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:489)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzd.zzc(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzd.zzi(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleIntent(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzc.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Here is the code

```
public class ToDoMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    try {
        Log.e("data", "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.e("data", "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        }
        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        String media_type = remoteMessage.getData().get("mt");
        String username = remoteMessage.getData().get("unm");
        String post_user_image = remoteMessage.getData().get("pui");
        String hqp_media = remoteMessage.getData().get("hqm");
        String hqp_created_date = remoteMessage.getData().get("hqcd");
        String hqp_body = remoteMessage.getData().get("hqb");
        String likes_on_post = remoteMessage.getData().get("lks");
        String postid = remoteMessage.getData().get("pid");
        String video_thumbnail = remoteMessage.getData().get("vt");
        String you_liked = remoteMessage.getData().get("ul");

        Log.e("title", title);
        Log.e("body", body);
        Log.e("media_type", media_type);
        Log.e("date", hqp_created_date);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(body)) {
            sendNotification(title, body, username, post_user_image, hqp_body, hqp_created_date, hqp_media, questid, likes_on_post, postid, video_thumbnail, you_liked, media_type);
        }
          } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

similar issue is here: -
[Error when push notification by postman but not when send by Firebase console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50819595/error-when-push-notification-by-postman-but-not-when-send-by-firebase-console)

Comment: @DudeCoder  this error not occur inside my code. this is the error i am updating

Comment: Post the relevant code for handling the message payload.

Comment: @AL.here it is i updated

Comment: i already fixed the issue.