# Why I can not get the notification data in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I'm trying to get the message data in my flutter app like this:

```
  firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
      const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, alert: true, badge: true));
  firebaseMessaging.configure(onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    print(" onLaunch called!" + message.toString());
  }, onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    print(" onMessage called!" + message.toString());
  }, onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    print(" onResume called!" + message.toString());
  });

  firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((iosNotificationSettings) {
    print("============ IOS settings registered!");
  });
```

the device is receiving the notification but I can not access that.
notification json:

```
{
    "notification": {
      "body": "body",
      "title": "title",
      "sound": "default"
    },
    "priority": "high",
    "data": {
      "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
    },
    "registration_ids": ["a token"]
  }
```

and every time I receive a notification I get this in the console:

```
W/FirebaseMessaging(22018): Error while parsing timestamp in GCM event
W/FirebaseMessaging(22018): java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
W/FirebaseMessaging(22018):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:483)
W/FirebaseMessaging(22018):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
W/FirebaseMessaging(22018):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb.zzc(Unknown Source)
W/FirebaseMessaging(22018):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.zzb.zze(Unknown Source)
W/FirebaseMessaging(22018):     at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzd(Unknown Source)
W/FirebaseMessaging(22018):     at com.google.firebase.iid.zzc.run(Unknown Source)
W/FirebaseMessaging(22018):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
W/FirebaseMessaging(22018):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
W/FirebaseMessaging(22018):     at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source)
W/FirebaseMessaging(22018):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

how can I get the message and the data sent with that notification?

Comment: What Flutter version are you using? Do you use the latest firebase_messaging plugin version?

Comment: Yes I updated just today and I'm using the master branch of flutter

Comment: I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50795697/android-firebase-error-while-parsing-timestamp-in-gcm-event-null-timestamp but I have `notification: {...}` in payload (and no `ttl: ...`) and don't get this error.

Comment: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/issues/784

Comment: Are you sending notifications by an api or using firebase console?

Answer (score 1):

```
print(message['body']);
```

try printing the message like this and see.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please consider improving your answer with some more details, such as what the problem with the original code is, and how your suggestion prevents that problem. Also, maybe you could repeat the original code with your fix applied, to make it a bit more clear where your suggestion belongs. See also [this post with tips on writing good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Good luck!

Comment: Add more explanation along with the code to provide the others a bit of understanding

Answer (score 0):

try message['title'].toString()
message['body'].toString()

Comment: Please consider improving your answer with some more details, such as what the problem with the original code is, and how your suggestion prevents that problem. Also, maybe you could repeat the original code with your fix applied, to make it a bit more clear where your suggestion belongs.

Comment: firebase sends the data in the type of json map,In order to print or use the data inside a map you should use the key value,So I retrived the data and used the 'title' key to know its value.