# Error while parsing timestamp in GCM event

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send push notifications to my android, when the push comes to the phone, the android logcat it reads `Error while parsing timestamp in GCM event` which makes it not display the data sent by the php script

```
$url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
$token = $gcmRegIds;
$serverKey = 'AIzxxyAZ_xxxxxxx-VjxxxxxcpHqqQU';
$title = "Alert from App";
$body = $headline;
$notification = array('title' =>$title , 'body' => $body);
$data = array("timestamp"=>date('Y-m-d G:i:s'), 'id' => $new_id,'display' => 'alert');
$arrayToSend = array('registration_ids' => $token, 'notification' => $notification, 'data' => $data);
$json = json_encode($arrayToSend);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: key='. $serverKey;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
//Send the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);
//Close request
if ($response === FALSE) {
die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this SO post about [Android/Firebase - Error while parsing timestamp in GCM event - Null timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50795697/android-firebase-error-while-parsing-timestamp-in-gcm-event-null-timestamp)? I think this can help you.

Comment: Adding your code on the Android side that handles the payload would be great.